# In magento, at "my account" dashboard for customers, while editing the account it accepts old password also for new password

Tags: magento, passwords

There is no alert message in magento, while typing old password at the new password textbox at "my account", frontend.

Comment: No this type of check available by default in magento

Comment: Can we change the default thing? How can i proceed?

Comment: First You need to rewrite `Mage_Customer_AccountController` controller in your custom module. then you can apply the check in `editPostAction` in .

Comment: ya right! Thanks for your help... Im trying to make changes over there...

Comment: if it works post your answer here for others help

Comment: if ($customer->hashPassword($newPass, $salt) == $oldPass) 
              {
            $errors[] = $this->__('Repeated passwords, Cannot be Replaced');
           }

Comment: write this code at line 919